# Replacing a class file inside a folder in a jar file

Tags: java, class, jar, directory

I have a jar file in `C:\` (`xx.jar`). I need to replace a class file (path: `com\sample\folder\xfile.class`) within `xx.jar` with a class file (`yfile.class`) that is placed `C:\`.

Please help me with the command for replacing one class file in the jar with another class file outside the jar. I am struggling in pointing the directory structure.

I tried with,

`jar uf C:\xx.jar C:\yfile.class`

The above command creates a **new** folder `C:\` within `xx.jar` and the `yfile.class` comes inside `C:\`. But I want the file to be inside the `com.sample.folder` in the `xx.jar`

Kindly help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't, really. Jar is really meant to package a prepared folder.
I guess this is also why maven etc create a build folder with everything that is going to end up in the jar/war/ear file.

```
jar uf C:\xx.jar C:\yfile.class
```

is indeed just adding the file to the archive.
In the folder you are archiving from you can use some -C directive, but that is about it. Suppose yout myfile.class is in a dir called C:\classes and you cal jar from that folder

```
jar uf C:\xx.jar -C .. classes\file.class
```

Is going to add the folder classes to the jar with the file myclass.class in it.

Kind regards